# What grammar domain is this kind of grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am new  to the concepts of grammars, but I need to figure out what grammar domain I am working in. I know it is not a context-free grammar (by reading the answers to [What does “context-free” mean in the term “context-free grammar”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/253454/104212)).

But is there a name or domain for what I am working in? Here is a brief description of it:

Say I have location data on some airplane trips. I have segmented it as follows:

OSTSL
where O is takeOff, S is Straight, T is Turn, and L is Landing.  The middle part, STS, could be considered a course correction if the change in heading is small (say < 5°), but I would call it a course change if change in heading is greater than 5°.

Thus T's have attributes. So if I want to characterize STS, I could call it a correctIon if TΔ < 5° and call it somethingElse if TΔ > 5°. But I could look at other attributes of T, such as radius or lateral acceleration. The point being it is not just based on there being an STS, but on certain qualities of T in STS. Also, in certain cases there will be a kind of "operator precedence" -- check this before checking that -- and the whole string STS has attributes such as STS_Timespan that can be used as a criteria.